# how to set up my mail

Tags: email, smtp

I'm just trying to figure out how to use the mail command from the command shell.
I've got Ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop. I've been entering the following:

```
user@hostname:~$ mail my_email_address@domain.com
```

It prompts for a `Cc:` and a `Subject:`, then I enter control D at the beginning of a line in order to complete.  I get an exit status of zero, but the mail never arrives.

I've also tried sending to local users, and that doesn't work either:

```
user@hostname:~$ mail other_user
```

I know there's something I need to set up that I haven't, I've just been unable to find it on the manpages or online.

Comment: I would recommend to use [mutt](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/mutt)

Comment: Nothing in your MTA's log file?

Comment: @Hauke Laging not sure what my MTA file is.

Answer (score 0):

The mail might not be going through due to your ISP.

This might help: [My ISP imposes SMTP restrictions on outgoing mail, is it possible to configure a system wide SMTP address?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/13072/my-isp-imposes-smtp-restrictions-on-outgoing-mail-is-it-possible-to-configure-a)

**If still a problem**, I would recommend you use some [other methods](https://askubuntu.com/questions/12917/how-to-send-mail-from-the-command-line) instead of mail.